# How I can to do a binding transformer with @expr data in google app maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a TABLE in google app maker, with two numbers, and a result: result= number1/number2

Number1 value is `datasource.item.Number1#formatNumber('#.00')`

Number2 value is `datasource.item.Number2#formatNumber('#.00')`

The result is `(@datasource.item.Number1/@datasource.item.Number2)#formatNumber('#.00')`

But , when I run this app, I have this error:

> Syntax Error: Unterminated statement at return
>   (_arg0/_arg1)#formatNumber('#.00')

I want that result to show in the table but with only 2 decimals.

How I can to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Let's first understand the reason behind the error. In Javascript, there is an operator called the **[ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**.

> The conditional (ternary) operator is the only JavaScript operator
>   that takes three operands. This operator is frequently used as a
>   shortcut for the **if statement**.

AppMaker thinks that you are putting a ternary operator and is trying to hint you that the syntax is not correct, hence you see that error.

Now that we've understand the error, let's focus on your need. So you want to use a binding transformer to format the result value to show two decimals only. The problem with the [#formatNumber](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/transformers#formatNumber) binding transformer is that it expects a primitive value **double** and you are providing an expression that evaluates to a number, which is not the same thing.

Fortunately, javascript have some built in methods that can help you achieve this. For this case, I'd go with **[toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)** method.

> The toFixed() method formats a number using fixed-point notation.

So all you have to do is change your binding expression to the following:

```
(@datasource.item.valueOne/@datasource.item.valueTwo).toFixed(2)
```